# Namespace problem in Struts2 when using Apache Tiles

Tags: java, namespaces, struts2, tiles2, apache-tiles

I have a simple problem when I come to Struts2. I use tiles plugin in my Struts2 project. As all of us know, tiles are used for making templates. We can give namespace for our package in struts.xml, the configuration file :

```
<package name="demo" namespace="/menu" extends="default">
```

and I gave namespace attribute to one of my link

```
<s:url action="hello" namespace="menu" />
```

All of these worked out well, still I could see my pages, but this time, when I add the above namespace to package definition in `struts.xml` and `s:url`, I lost my tiles definition. I lost my tiles template, styles(css) and settings. But without using this namespace, I can access my pages with tiles.

Please help me, where did i go wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The above problem partially solved.

Comment: namespace has nothing to do with tiles. May be you should be more specific.

Comment: Provide your tiles.xml configuration. I'm sorry i'm new this community I think there might be some problem in tiles configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think this Link can help you
[Struts2 tiles integration](http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-tiles-example-1.html).
Try to compare your files with that example. We are unable to understand your problem without much details.